# Loading a sound track from the middle of sound file

Tags: actionscript-3, air, airplay

When users try to watch a clip on youtube, on the player,  they can choose to watch it from middle of clip or the begining or from nearly the end or from any point they like. in other words they should not watch the clip from the begining to the end and they have the freedom to click on any part of the timeline and watch the clip from the point that they wish.

I have sound files in mp3 format and I would like my users to listen to sound from anywhere on timeline that they wish, at the begining , middle or any part of sound track.

Please advise me.
How can I do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You really should check out the documentation before asking here.

This answer has been sourced from docs found [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7cf8.html)

```
var req = new air.URLRequest("soundFile.mp3"); 
var snd = new Sound(req); 
snd.play(); //plays a sound file from the beginning

var start:Number=5 * 1000; //5 seconds
var loop:int=1;
snd.play(start, loop); //Play sound from start milliseconds, loop time
```